# Diffie-Hellman over $GF(2^{128})$

Tags: diffie-hellman, finite-field

Can I use Diffie-Hellman over, say, $GF(2^{128}) \bmod$ irreducible poly in $GF(2^{128})$ instead of $GF(p)$?
If not, why?

Or increase it to $GF(2^{2^{\text{whatever}}})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use a randomly chosen prime field.

First of all, $GF(2^{2^{whatever}})$ is nonsensical. The field is still $GF(2^k)$ for some $k.$

The security of Diffie Hellman rests on the difficulty of discrete logarithms.

The discrete logarithm problem for fields of the form $GF(2^k)$ is much easier, having quasi-polynomial algorithms developed by Joux and others for some values of $k$. See also the answer to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48767/the-computational-complexity-of-discrete-log) where the complexity for general $k$ of the form you are asking is stated as:

As for the case of $q=2^k$, the best asymptotic complexity is provided by [Barbulescu et al.'s version](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48767/the-computational-complexity-of-discrete-log) of the function field sieve (FFS), which in that case runs in heuristic quasipolynomial time $2^{O((\log k)^2)}$.

Even for prime fields $GF(p)$, if the prime is *known ahead of time* there are attacks  [state actors can mount](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29871/state-level-weak-diffie-hellman-working-for-srp-too), but $p$ is randomly chosen for proper implementation of Diffie Hellman, thwarting those attacks.

Comment: Given the https://weakdh.org/ attacks I would say if you go to something like 3k bits it's probably acceptable to use a fixed prime, right?

Comment: @Elias, I believe so, but my expertise in this area is not that deep. You might want to ask a separate question.